# finding which sub string comes first, which comes second and which comes third

Tags: java, string, substring

```
String s="CCATGTTGGCCTAGGTGACAC";
```

I am trying to find an Open reading frame from above DNA sequence. First I have to find whether there is "ATG" present as a sub string. If it is there then I have to find out whether any one of these sub strings is present "TAA", "TAG", "TGA". Among these three sub strings whichever comes first is to be taken into considerartion and then I would print the string from "ATG" to "TAA" or "TAG" or "TGA" whichever comes first.
From above string output should be "ATG TTGGCC TAG".

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achive. The test data "junk" `"ddddeeaxgghnnnbykkkkkklllllczfr"` does not help at all to understand your problem. Any chance to see your code where you tried to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of each substring..

```
System.out.println(s.indexOf("ax"));
```

The one whose index is minimum is the one who comes first.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String testString = "ddddeeaxgghnnnbykkkkkklllllczfr";


    String[] frags = testString.split("(ax|by|cz)");
    if(frags.length >= 1) {
        System.out.println("first=" + frags[0]);
        if(frags.length >= 2) {
            System.out.println("second=" + frags[1]);
            if(frags.length >= 3) {
                System.out.println("third=" + frags[2]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("nothing found");
    }
```

It prints:

> first=ddddee
>   second=gghnnn
>   third=kkkkkklllll