# Why won't this code for solving which word comes first or second work by user input too?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

Nevermind - didn't want to delete question, so I'm updating. I didn't notice I used next() instead of nextLine().

Credit to: [finding which sub string comes first, which comes second and which comes third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29033390/finding-which-sub-string-comes-first-which-comes-second-and-which-comes-third)

That's where I saw the code. I found what I was looking for, but when I tried the code using scanner, it wouldn't show me all the words which came first, which second, and which third. It only showed me which came first. When I wrote the same words using string, it gave me the answers, but when I used scanner, it would only show me the first word.

Here's the code:

```
String testString = s.next();
String[] frags = testString.split("( )"); //Inside the brackets were letters, but I replaced them with a space.
if(frags.length >= 1) {  //Also could someone explain to me why should the length be greater(or equal) to 1, 2, and 3?
    System.out.println("first=" + frags[0]);
    if(frags.length >= 2) {
        System.out.println("second=" + frags[1]);
        if(frags.length >= 3) {
            System.out.println("third=" + frags[2]);
        }
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("nothing found");
}
```

Comment: should you be using nextLine instead of next? I doubt that you really want to split on `( )`. what is the delimiter for your data? finally, your last question indicates that you do not understand arrays. Read the documentation or a tutorial about arrays.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

> **Title:** Why won't this code for solving which word comes first or second work
>   by user input too?

Are you expecting your User(s) to enter strings which contain open and close parentheses with whitespace in the middle? For example:

```
Hi( )my( )name( )is( )Jane.
```

Maybe you are but for some reason I doubt it. When people are to enter a string of text they generally use a whitespace to separate the words. With this in mind your [**String.split()**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) method should take that into account. What you would most likely want to use to ***split*** the User supplied text with is this little [**Regular Expression**](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html):

```
"\\s+"
```

What this expression does when applied to the **String.split()** method is that it will split the string based on one ***or more*** white-spaces. Your code line should really look like this:

```
String[] frags = testString.split("\\s+");
```

Using a literal white-space with split would also work:

```
String[] frags = testString.split(" ");
```

but using the above regular expression takes care of any spacing scenario.

If by chance however you do expect the User to supply text with parenthesized content to separate the words (or perhaps your getting the strings from a file) then you can use this little regular expression with the **String.split()** method:

```
"\\((.*?)\\)"
```

This will allow the split method to split the User supplied string by Open and Close parentheses regardless of what is contained within those parentheses:

```
String[] frags = testString.split("\\((.*?)\\)");
```

> **Code Comment:** Also could someone explain to me why should the length be greater(or
>   equal) to 1, 2, and 3

**frags** is an Array where indexing is 0 based (first array element is at index 0...not 1). The **Array.length** attribute always returns the literal length of the Array whereas the first element of the Array is actually considered as at position 1 of the Array.

[image]

The first **if** condition merely ensures that there is indeed an array element at index 0 and that the Array is at least 1 element long (at least one word was supplied). Since the condition for this **if** statement was successful (condition was true) why not see if we can be successful with a second **if** statement to see if a second word was supplied (at least two words were supplied). And what the heck, if the second **if** statement condition was deemed to be true then let's go for the third **if** statement to see if three or more words were at least supplied. There are only three words you're after here.

The length of the Array basically tells you how many words were supplied:

```
System.out.println("Words supplied by User is: " + frags.length);
```

but this is only true if the **String.split()** method was successful.

**Things to consider:**

What if a User supplied nothing (just hit enter)? Yes, that would get split too but the array would have a length of 1 (1 element at index 0) and the element would be a Null String (**""**). You will need to handle this situation should it ever *accidentally* arise. So, to put it mildly, no matter what the User supplies (other than quitting) there will always be something found, The **else** statement will never get hit. It would most likely be a better idea to utilize the **"nothing found"** thingy for testing whether or not a valid string was supplied:

```
if (testString == null || testString.equals("")) {
    System.out.println("Nothing Supplied!");
    return;
}
```

and this should be placed before you even carry out a split. Why bother processing an empty string?

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
String testString = scan.nextLine();

if (testString.equals("")) {
    System.out.println("Nothing Supplied! Quitting!");
    System.exit(0);
}

String[] frags = testString.split("\\s+"); 

if (frags.length >= 1) {  
    System.out.println("First word is:\t" + frags[0]);
    if (frags.length >= 2) {
        System.out.println("Second word is:\t=" + frags[1]);
        if (frags.length >= 3) {
            System.out.println("Third word is:\t" + frags[2]);
        }
    }
}
```